# php - error in Autopopulate not working

Tags: php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="">Member No of the Transferer<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input required="" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="old_member_no" type="number" name="old_member_no" <?php if(isset($editData)) echo  'readonly style="pointer-events: none;"'; ?> value="{{ old('old_member_no',isset($editData) ? $editData->old_member_no:"") }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="member_no" value="{{ old('member_no',isset($editData) ? $editData->member_no:"") }}" />
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="">Name of the Transferer<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
        <input required="" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="" type="text" name="full_name" value="{{ old('full_name',isset($editData) ? $editData->full_name:"") }}">
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="">Address of the Transferer<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
        <input required="" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="house" type="text" name="house" value="{{ old('house',isset($editData) ? $editData->house:"") }}">
    </div>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
```

Hello guys. I'm doing a project. I'm developing a form with autopopulate. If number is typed and after pressing enter the address and name should be fetched from database. kindly help me

Comment: Hello. What kind of help do you need? What have you tried so far? What's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not clear to me but base on your descriptions... You would need to use Javascript/JQuery here and use Event functions when the entering a field